# Handling large iterators - aggregation

Tags: scala

1. Let's say we have an Iterator of a (String, String)-Tuple.
2. Said Iterator has a kazillion elements, possibly exhausting main memory.

What would you do if you had to aggregate it like the following:

The tuples have the form of `(entityname, attributename)` and you would have to populate a list of the `attributenames`. Also the iterator would be completely unordered and would never fit into memory.

(for instance the last and the first attibutename could correspond to the same entityname).

A concrete example:

```
("stackoverflow","users"),
("bear","claws"),
("stackoverflow","usesAjaxTechnology"),
("bear","eyes")
```

after the aggregation -> :

```
("stackoverflow",List("users","usesAjaxTechnology")),
("bear",List("claws","eyes")).
```

I know that there are statemenst like `groupBy` and so on but this would assuming the iterator has a lof ot elements never work due to memory problems?

Comment: Yours is a good question, but it'd be nice if you'd put some more effort into properly formatting it. Punctuation is also always good to increase readability. The better formatted and readable an answer is, the more likely it is for people to answer it (at least for non-obvious questions :D)

Comment: Have an accumulator (something from `mutable._` (`HashMap[String, HashSet[String]]`?)) and run through the iterator populating the accumulator. Thus you will have the control over the memory footprint. For instance, when you see that there are too many elements, you may squeeze the oldest to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets take a look at what groupBy does:

```
scala> res0.groupBy(x => x._1)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[(String, String)]] = 
    Map( bear -> List((bear,claws), (bear,eyes)),
         stackoverflow -> List((stackoverflow,users), (stackoverflow,usesAjaxTechnology))
    )
```

As you can see, it creates a `Map` of elements. Since it does so in memory, you'd obviously run into memory issues as the data grows larger than your RAM.

On the other hand, it'd be possible to construct a Map-like structure that, instead of holding all data in memory, writes them to the filesystem. The simplest such Map would create a file for every key (e.g. "bear" or "stackoverflow") in a certain directory, and write all the attributes into the corresponding files. This would require almost no memory usage, replacing it with very high disk usage.

I'm wondering if this is sort of an artificial requirement, or if you are actually facing a real problem where this is an issue. Also, I'm really interested in hearing what the real functional programming pros here have to say :)

Comment: Obviously you can write anything to file. I was like you looking for a   non sied effecty solution (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

If you have that many elements I would assume that they are in a database or file of some type . I would take them out in manageable chunks and process them that way, writing them back to a db or new file. That would solve your problem with memory and allow you to perform this kind of processing.

If you are using MongoDb( which I recommend) your find query could easily pull out only the stackoverflow users and then your next statement could write that to a new collection. Same with the bear.

Comment: How could you possibly fit MongoDB (or any other concrete DB technology for that matter) into an answer to such a general question?  :D It's like getting the question "Hey, do you know how I can move from A to B in a fast and comfortable manner?" and you answering "Yeah, I recommend you to get a Mercedes"...

Comment: Easy the user is asking how to process more data than will fit into ram, so the data has to originate from somewhere? Also it has to be stored somewhere. The question is more like "how I can move ten million bricks with my hatchback" the answer is "you need a dump truck".

Comment: Except when he needs to move them off an island, in which case a ship might be in order. Or there might not be any roads leading to where the bricks are, so maybe a helicopter? If there is a runway close, he might use a plane though. Or, if the bricks only need to be moved 10 meters, pushcart and a couple of workers might totally suffice. Why would you make somebody buy a dumptruck if the person lives on an island ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, by the way. I just think that MongoDB doesn't have to do anything with it and should be omitted since it is totally subjective.

Comment: Lol apparently someone agrees. I just can't think of a real world way to get more data than will fit into ram into an application or out of an application without a text file or db of some kind.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't have mentioned "a database", or even something more specific like "a schema-less, document oriented database", or even "a document oriented database like MongoDB". But the way you wrote it, it just sounds too subjective.

Comment: Someone seems to be quite triggerhappy with the downvote button?

Comment: Good to know I am new to stackoverflow and that was my first answer. I suppose I need to learn the etiquette and verbiage of the community. Thanks for the tip. Also mongo is just what I am familiar with, so it was the first thing to come to mind.